# JQuery validate triggered every time the browser gets the focus

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-validate, validation

I am using jquery validation plugin to validate my form. I have one field that I don't want to validate but in some way it is validated anyway and I get the error message "Please enter no more than 5 characters."

The field that is validated is a type=file field and I use it together with the Fynework jQuery  MultiForm plugin. It's not validated when I try to submit the form, only when I chose file that has a name longer than 5 characters (I think, short names work long doesn't).

I have tried adding the class .ignore to the field that is validated and added that the ignore rule to my validat(), not difference in behaviour.

What can the problem be?

**Here is my validat() method**, I also include the point at which I add that method:

```
function addNewTicketValidation(){
                  $("#newticketform").validate({ 
                            ignore: ".ignore",
                            errorContainer: "#messageBox1",
                            errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox1 ul",
                            wrapper: "li", 
                            debug:true,
                            rules: {     
                             title: "required",                                  
                             description: "required"                                                                                     
                            }, 
                            messages: { 
                              title: "Titel saknas", 
                              description: "Beskrivning saknas" 
                            }
                          }); 
                    } 

      $("#newticketmanu").live('click',function(event){
          $("#adminarea").load("http://" + hostname + "/" + compdir + "/modules/core/newticket/newticket.php", function(){
                  $('#my_file_element').MultiFile();                    
                  addNewTicketValidation();  

          });
      });
```

**My form:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="newticketform" class="MultiFile-intercepted" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input type="hidden" value="2000000" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE">
        <label for="title">Rubrik</label> <input type="text" name="title" id="title"><br><br>
        <label for="description">Beskrivning</label> <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="50" rows="15"></textarea><br> 

         <div id="my_file_element_wrap" class="MultiFile-wrap"><input type="file" maxlength="5" name="file[]" id="my_file_element" class="multi ignore MultiFile-applied" value=""><div id="my_file_element_wrap_list" class="MultiFile-list"></div></div>
         <div id="files_list"></div>
         <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload"> 
</form>
```

What can the problem be and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the maxlength="5" attribute from the file input. This is read by the validation plugin and added as a rule (line 812 here https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/1.9.0/jquery.validate.js). Checking the specifications (http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/i/inputfile.htm), max length still means character length even on a file input, so if you want to limit the user to 5 file uploads you'll need some other method of achieving this.

Comment: Thanks! I see. So the problem is that there is a conflict between the plugins since MultiFile uses maxlength as an attribute? But is validation-plugin caring about attributes, I thought it used only 'name'? It did work when I removed the maxlength so it was for sure the root cause.

Comment: And to solve the actual problem one can use class instead. E.g. class='max-2' sets the max number of files to 2. This is not conflicting with the maxlength attribute.